# Some images do not show in prestashop

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, browser-cache

I have an online store from prestashop but suddenly some pictures on my site can not show up, i try debug with google chrome element inspector, here i show the result in the picture, somebody help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8R2b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/242048-solved-images-not-showing/) it will help you